# Disable omnisharp-vscode's "project selector" feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm using vscode 1.58.0 and omnisharp-vscode 1.23.14.

The latest update introduced a feature of a dropdown that asks me to choose a project. All other projects are disabled, i.e. not analyzed by omnisharp. This forces me to continually switch between projects.

Can I load multiple projects at a time?

Better yet, can I can revert to the old behavior of loading all projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, which the latest version [fixed](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4691).